# How to pull a commit from a branch in git

Tags: git-branch, git-pull

I have two commits in my branch.
How can I pull the first  from command line in my local repository?
I have two commits under branch 'foo'. With messag "xyz" and "abc"  and with some numbers written "efc204e" and "33481e8" respectively

Comment: Use `git cherry-pick` and then the commit.

Comment: Can you just pull the two commits then reset to the one you want to work on ?

Comment: @PatJ how to pull both the commits?

Comment: Just pull the entire branch.

Comment: @PatJ And how to reset?

Comment: `git reset hashofyourcommit` (that would be in that case your `efc204e`).

Answer (score 0):

```
git pull 
git reset efc204e
```

..

Comment: Can you explain your answer please ?

Comment: Yes, first pull the entire branch which will pull the both commits. Then reset the last commit done (efc204e) so now you have a branch with only '33481e8' commmit.